# How do I measure groove separation?

Tags: measurements, cad, metallurgy

In this drawing it says that each groove is separated by 5deg. Each groove has a depth of .015", the radius of the contour is 0.47"

[image]

How do I measure the separation of each groove?

My sketch is incorrect as it leaves too much space on the edges:
[image]

---

**Update:**

I think I solved it. The measurement between the grooves is from the midpoint of a groove to the edge of the next one:

[image]

This matches the drawing. But I would like to know if this is the standard way to measure distance between grooves.

Comment: "Too much space on which edge"? Are you comparing to the image? is that "real" or an artist's impression?

Comment: @SolarMike The first image is the drawing from the part in the blueprint, it shows how it should be. The second image is what I have in the CAD software. When I say edge I mean in the first image in the top and bottom. You can see that the space between the fist and last groove is not as large as in my current sketch.

Comment: The pcd will affect the tooth / gap spacing.

Comment: The primary difference I see is that the upper sketch shows (and the caption calls out) 9 grooves, where you've drawn only 5. But based on the apparent radius in the upper drawing, it looks reasonable that the 9 grooves subtend a total of around 40-45 degrees, tending to confirm that they're around 5 degrees apart.

Comment: You seem to have assumed that the grooves are like gear teeth which have protrusions and cuts above and below the nominal line. The isometric drawing suggests that the top of the teeth are level with the diameter of the smooth portion of the disc. There is no dimension for the depth or width of the groove so you have no way to reproduce.